# Apply custom filter with a custom window matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, kernel, extract

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
I'v a kernel made of 0's and 1's ,
e.g a crosslike kernel

kernel =

```
 0     1     0
 1     1     1
 0     1     0
```

and I need to apply it to a given matrix like

D =

```
16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1
```

for semplicity let's assume to start from element D(2,2), wich is 11, to avoid padding (that I can do with padarray).
I should superimpose the kernel and extract only elements where kernel==1, i.e 
[2,5,11,10,7] then apply on them a custom filter like median or average and replacing central element with the result. 
Then I would like to pass through all other elements (neglect edge elements for semplicity) and do the same.
Now I'm using `tempS= ordfilt2(Z,order,kernel,'symmetric');`
that performs exactly that operation with median filter. But I would like to use a different criterion (i.e. the average or some weird operation )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`blockproc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html). This also handles border effects automatically (see the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)). For example, to compute the median of the values masked by the kernel:

```
mask = logical(kernel);
R = blockproc(D, [1 1], @(d) median(d.data(mask)), ...
    'bordersize', [1 1], 'trimborder', 0);
```

The first `[1 1]` indicated the step. The second `[1 1]` indicates how many elements to take around the central one.

With your example `D`, the result is

```
R =
     2     3     3     3
     9     7     8    10
     5     9    10     6
     4     7     6     1
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'll try ... I tried with blockproc but i wasn't able to apply my mask.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
D = rand(10,20);
kernel = [0,1,0;1,1,1;0,1,0];
[dy,dx] = find(kernel==1);
% should be calculated from kernel
dy = dy-2;
dx = dx-2;
% start and stop should calculated by using kernel size
result = zeros(size(D));
for y = 2:(size(D,1)-1)
    for x = 2:(size(D,2)-1)
        elements = D(sub2ind(size(D),y+dy,x+dx));
        result(y,x) = weirdOperation(elements);
    end
end
```

Nevertheless this will perform very poorly in terms of speed. You should consider use builtin functions. `conv2` or `filter2` for linear filter operations. `ordfilt2` for order-statistic funtionality.